# Access insert opened query in excel below existing data

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

Ok, so I have an Excel-file with data. This data comes from a query that has been manually copied from an Access database. Since this has to be done every day we want to make it automatically.

I already have VBA code inside the Access database that opens the query and writes it away into the Excel-file on the right sheet.
However, it works when I put a static range for the insert so it actually just overwrites the range I say:

```
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim ApXL As Object
Dim xlWBk As Object
Dim xlWSh As Object

Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Query name")

Set ApXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

ApXL.Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ApXL.Visible = True

Set xlWBk = ApXL.Workbooks.Open("C:\blabla.xlsm", True, False)
Set xlWSh = xlWBk.Worksheets(1)

xlWSh.Activate

xlWSh.range("A1341").CopyFromRecordset rst

xlWBk.Save
xlWBk.Close False

ApXL.Quit

rst.Close

Set rst = Nothing
```

Notice the xlWSh.range("A1341").CopyFromRecordset rst.
It just pastes the query from this row because I know this is the first empty row.

I already tried lots of other codes but I always get errors:

```
TheLastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
=> Error 424: Object required

Dim MyRange As range
Dim lngLastRow As Long
Set MyRange = xlWSh.range(strColum & "1")
lngLastRow = xlWSh.Cells(65536, MyRange.Column).End(xlUp).Row
=> Compilation-error on Dim MyRange As range: user-defined type not defined

Dim MyRange As Object
Dim lngLastRow As Long
Set MyRange = xlWSh.range(strColum & "1")
lngLastRow = xlWSh.Cells(65536, MyRange.Column).End(xlUp).Row
=> Error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error

With xlWBk.Sheets("Sheetname")
lastrow = .range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
=> Error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error
End With

With xlWSh
lastrow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=.range("A1"), SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
=> Error 9: Subscript out of range
End With
```

So I have no idea anymore what to do.
The only other option is by reading the entire sheet into the Access database as a List or Array or Table and then do a .Count or something but inserting into lastRow+1 or firstEmptyRow should be quicker, doable and much easier to program.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Access doesn't know anything about Excel constants, such as `xlUp`, `xlByRows` and so on (until you add reference to excel library).

There are to ways for you:

1) Go to *TOOLS->REFERENCES* and add reference to *Microsoft Excel 1x.0 Object Library* (version may vary)

[image]

2) change all excel constants to their values (e.g. change `SearchOrder:=xlByRows` to `SearchOrder:=1` and so on):

- `xlUp` equals to `-4162`
- `xlByRows` eqals to `1`
- `xlPrevious` eqals to `2`
- `xlCellTypeLastCell` equals to `11`

Here is link with values of excel constants: [**xlConstants**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221100(v=office.11).aspx) (or another way to determine constants values - is to use this line in **EXCEL VBA** : `MsgBox xlCellTypeLastCell`)

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response.
I used the 2nd option with this code:
`lastrow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=.range("A1"), SearchOrder:=1, SearchDirection:=2).Row + 1`
And this works perfect!